# Viewing Image from database

Tags: php, sql, file

I have a file in which a user can view its stored files. I want that only the logged in user and it can only be viewed by that member who has stored that file. It works fine when I view other files like .*html*, .*txt* etc. But when I view any image, it doesn't work.

This is my script :

```
require ('config.php');
$id = intval($_GET['id']);

$dn2 = mysql_query('select authorid from files where uploadid="'.$id.'"');

while($dnn2 = mysql_fetch_array($dn2))
{
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and ($_SESSION['userid']==$dnn2['authorid'] or $_SESSION['username']==$admin)){ 

 $query = "SELECT data, filetype FROM files where uploadid=$id"; //Find the file, pull the filecontents and the filetype
    $result = MYSQL_QUERY($query);    // run the query

    if($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) // pull the first row of the result into an array(there will only be one)
    {
        $data = $row[0];    // First bit is the data
        $type = $row[1];    // second is the filename

        Header( "Content-type: $type"); // Send the header of the approptiate file type, if it's' a image you want it to show as one :)
        print $data; // Send the data.
    }
    else // the id was invalid
    {
        echo "invalid id";
    }
}
}
```

How can I view the image?

Comment: What happens when you try to view an image?

Comment: Can you echo out the `$type`, instead of writing it to the header?

Comment: yes i echo out the $type

Comment: .... and what does it show? Is it correct? When you echo it out, and the data, is the the data showing up properly?

Comment: @user2863182 Try putting your `$id` inside quotes like this `SELECT data, filetype FROM files where uploadid='$id'` see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @user2863182 Plus, does your data have a way/method to show the image itself, as in `<img src='image_1.jpg'>` ? How are you trying to show the image itself and what is the field/row called?

Comment: no there is no way to show image itself

Comment: @user2863182 So it's for `?id=3` that it shows an icon. Strange, when I tried `?id=2` it showed me the photo of a person. So with that said, what is the actual problem then? I don't quite understand where/what the problem is. Evidently, your `id=3` is a local to DB issue.

Comment: that file is not the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [show image from blob mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907361/show-image-from-blob-mysql)